# The condition $\det(I)=1$, and the uniqueness of the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, determinant

The third condition for the definition of a determinant is given as $\det(I)=1$ (multi-linear and alternating are the first two conditions). Why is this important? Does it relate to the uniqueness of the determinant? What exactly is meant by uniqueness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary to have $\det(I)=1$ in order for $\det$ to be not totally trivial ($0$ for every matrix) and still satisfy the property $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. Observe that if $\det(I)=a$ for some number $a\neq 0,1$, then
$$\det(I^2)=\det(I)=a\neq a^2=\det(I)\det(I)$$
The property $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ is extremely important, both theoretically (it makes the function $\det:\mathrm{GL}_n(K)\to K^\times$ a [*group homomorphism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism)) and computationally.

With regards to your question about uniqueness: one common way of defining the determinant (which it sounds like is the way it's the way you're using) is to first propose considering functions $f:\mathrm{M}_{n\times n}(K)\to K$ that are (a) multilinear, (b) alternating, and (c) have $f(I)=1$; and then showing that in fact there is a unique such function, and we give that function the name "determinant".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Zev! Is it then this property that is then referred to as uniqueness.